# Positioning Scale Control In Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I tried to re-position the Scale Control like this

```
scaleControl: true,
  scaleControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
}
```

at [This Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/z1c602Ld/) but it seems it is not working! can you please let me know if it is possible to re-positin ans apply some style (To Highlight it) to Scale Control? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are no configurable  [options for a scaleControl](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#ScaleControlOptions), the position may not be modified